# Query on C exercise

Tags: c

From the link 
http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node8.html#SECTION00840000000000000000

Exercise 12347

I am not able to understand the meaning of these 2 points in the question.

1)

- The total number of characters after tab expansion
- The total number of spaces after tab expansion
- The total number of leading spaces after tab expansion

2)

NOTE: All tab characters ('') on input should be interpreted as multiple spaces using the rule:

"move to the next modulo 8 column"

where the first column is numbered column 0.

```
    col before tab | col after tab

    ---------------+--------------
            0      |      8
            1      |      8
            7      |      8
            8      |     16
            9      |     16
           15      |     16
           16      |     24
```

Sham

Comment: SO is not for your homework . Do homework yourself.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor cut the attitude. He is not asking to solve the homework

Answer (score 3):

It's simple enough once you understand. Tab expansion is the act of replacing tabs with a series of spaces, the quantity of which will move you to the next tab stop.

So, for example, let's consider tabstops at columns 8, 16 and so on. The first line below will be tab-expanded to the second (assuming `.` is the tab):

```
         11111111112
12345678901234567890 <- Ruler line
--------------------
hi.there
hi     there
```

You can see that the single tab has been expanded into five spaces so that the next character starts on the tabstop at column 8.

So you just need to re-examine those questions in light of that information.